# How to use Terminal to navigate into a desktop shortcut or folder in applications?

Tags: macos, terminal.app

I'm on a Mac and watching a tutorial on setting up Git.

I'm in the terminal and currently on the Desktop. I can us ls to list all the items on my desktop, and cd into any of the folders on my Desktop, but I can't get into my localhost shortcut (which leads to the MAMP folder in applications where all my websites are).

Error message:

[image]

1) How do you navigate into a shortcut, or

2) How do you navigate into the Main Mac folder (I can't see or cd into it from the terminal)

Comment: `file localhost` says...?

Comment: when I type that in, it displays 'data'

Comment: Did you mean to create it as a symlink initially?

Comment: Not sure what that means, I just put a shortcut there, because I'm too scared of accidentally deleting my projects folder. So a shortcut makes it safer :) Do I need to remake the shortcut / alias?

Comment: I would remove the shortcut and create a symlink instead.

Comment: If you want to keep the alias and follow that, see: [OS X terminal command to resolve path of an alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175094/os-x-terminal-command-to-resolve-path-of-an-alias)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get to the Main Mac folder, you can do `cd /`

Comment: Thanks! I can now cd into my Applications > MAMP folder :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Terminal

```
ln -s /Applications/source/path /Users/name/target/path
```

which in your case (if I've understood correctly) should be

```
ln -s /Applications/MAMP ~/Desktop/localhost
```

which will create a symbolic link on your Desktop which will be accessible both through the finder and by entering `cd localhost` while in `~/Desktop`.

If you only need this link for quick access via Terminal, I would recommend placing it into your home folder which would allow you to access it by entering `cd localhost` as soon as you open a new Terminal shell.

Comment: Just tried that again, and can't CD into an alias :(

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my answer was wrong, I revised it.